# Angularjs unit testing service with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a service that uses a repository which in turn returns a promise to the consumer.
I'm having trouble testing the promise, or I should say I don't know how test the promise.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why you use promises on your test. I would just return the value on the getData spy. On test angular does not call `$scope.$digest()` this must be call manually when using $httpBackend module. I suggest you use $httpBackend to mock the ajax call and then `$scope.digest`

Comment: The above comment is wrong i confused the digest cycle with the flush method of $httpBackend. Anyway when testing a directive ort a controller might be helpfull to use the digest method of the $scope object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the test with [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#flushing-http-requests) and for mocking the service.

```
var describe = window.describe,
    beforeEach = window.beforeEach,
    afterEach = window.afterEach,
    it = window.it,
    expect = window.expect,
    inject = window.inject,
    module = window.module,
    angular = window.angular,
    serviceURL = '/' + Techsson.Core.Global.Language + '/api/sessionlimit/getdata',
    $scope,
    sessionLimitServiceResponse;

describe('Jasmine - SessionLimitService', function () {

    beforeEach(module('sessionlimit.module'));

    var sessionLimitServiceMock, q;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_SessionLimitService_, _SessionLimitResository_, $httpBackend, $rootScope) {
        sessionLimitServiceMock = _SessionLimitService_;
//remove the use of global variables
    $httpBackend.when('GET', serviceURL)
                            .respond('foo', {/*Headers*/});
        }));

    it("Content array must be empty", function () {
        expect(sessionLimitServiceMock.content.length).toEqual(0);
    });

    it('Content array must have a value', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET(serviceURL);
        sessionLimitServiceMock.getData().then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toEqual('foo'); // NOTHING HAPPENS
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get value as undefined in the above example. Pls see the edit above.

Comment: Yep, right it is `$httpBackend.flush()` instead of `$scope.$digest()` according to docs. I'll update the example

Comment: Hi again! I'm still getting the value as undefined...I updated the code above again...

Comment: I updated the code . I forgot to use `$httpBackend.expectGET`. It is good to add an `afterEach` too as on the docs: `  afterEach(function() {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });`